# Displaying a currency from a number

Tags: javascript, jquery, numbers, format

How can I change a number ( integer ) into a currency format while live input/typing?

ex :

```
45678 => 456.78
```

or

```
234567 => 2345.67  or 2,345.67 or 2 345.67
```

( depending on the mask format used )

Before people start tagging this question as an existing one, I have already seen the existing codes that format numbers, but those examples do not handle the last two numbers as decimals. Instead those format the string 45678 into 45 678.00 or 45,678.00 instead of 456.78.

Something like convert:

`######## into ### ###.##`

Comment: `(number / 100).toFixed(2)`

Comment: If you are using angular try https://angular.io/api/common/CurrencyPipe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could iterate the mask and reassemble the result string.

It creates from both values two arrays (with [spread syntax `...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator)) for a single number or mask character in an array.

Then it iterates the mask characters from the right side and

```
(m === '#' ? v.pop() || '' : v.length ? m : '') + s
```

builds a new string with either a numerical value, if `#` is found

```
 m === '#' ? v.pop() || ''
```

or takes the value of the mask by checking the length of the values

```
                             v.length ? m : ''
```

to prevent adding spaces or unwanted characters.

```js
function convert(i, mask) {
    var v = [...i.toString()];
    return [...mask].reduceRight((s, m) => (m === '#' ? v.pop() || '' : v.length ? m : '') + s, '');
}

console.log(convert(45678, '### ###.##')); // 456.78
console.log(convert(234567, '### ###.##')); // 2345.67
console.log(convert(234567, '###,###.##')); // 2,345.67
console.log(convert(234567, '### ###.##')); // 2 345.67
```

Comment: Can you please explain because I cant get you what you have done

Answer (score 1):

Add an event handler for when you type into the input to format the value for that input.

```
$('#myTextbox').keyup(function(){
    $(this).val(($(this).val() /100).toFixed(2);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

(number).toFixed() function converts a number to string. To avoid this try:

```
var x4 = 999546765687;
x4 = x4/100;
x4.toFixed(2);
Number(x4)
```

Answer (score 0):

> The [toLocaleString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString) method returns a string with a language sensitive representation of this number.

```js
var currency = 234567/100;
var currencyString = currency.toLocaleString('en-US')
console.log(currencyString);
```

Answer (score 0):

For angular

https://angular.io/api/common/CurrencyPipe

Try using
   @Component({
      selector: 'currency-pipe',
      template: `

A: {{a | currency}}

```
    <!--output 'CA$0.26'-->
    <p>A: {{a | currency:'CAD'}}</p>

    <!--output 'CAD0.26'-->
    <p>A: {{a | currency:'CAD':'code'}}</p>

    <!--output 'CA$0,001.35'-->
    <p>B: {{b | currency:'CAD':'symbol':'4.2-2'}}</p>

    <!--output '$0,001.35'-->
    <p>B: {{b | currency:'CAD':'symbol-narrow':'4.2-2'}}</p>

    <!--output '0 001,35 CA$'-->
    <p>B: {{b | currency:'CAD':'symbol':'4.2-2':'fr'}}</p>
  </div>`
})
export class CurrencyPipeComponent {
  a: number = 0.259;
  b: number = 1.3495;
}
```